# Google Maps marker offset by 30px down

Tags: google-maps

I have Google map marker that I would LOVE to move down by 30 px. I try to set `new google.maps.Point(0, 30)`, but it places the marker somewhere diagonal in wrong place. 
I just need to move it down.
Here is my code:

```
var markerSize;
if (icon.substring(icon.length-9) == '-main.png') {
    markerSize = new google.maps.Size(102,102);
} else {
    markerSize = new google.maps.Size(31,42);
}

var iconSized = new google.maps.MarkerImage(icon, null, null, null, markerSize);
```

Comment: Where did you set the `new google.maps.Point(0, 30)`?

Comment: 4th parameter in `google.maps.MarkerImage`

Comment: Hmm.. that should work.. can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: I fixed the problem tho really don't know why i needed to do that...
I needed to set this `new google.maps.Point(52, 71)`. In general, Image is resized with help of Google API, tho really don't know why I needed to set such strange numbers, tho all works fine.